# How to create a QSet of iterators

Tags: c++, qt, hash, iterator

What I am trying to do is:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QLinkedList>
#include <QSet>

class MyType
{
//...
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QVector<MyType> vector;
    QSet<QVector<MyType>::iterator> a;
    a.insert(vector.begin());          // This is fine

    QLinkedList<MyType> linkedList;
    QSet<QLinkedList<MyType>::iterator> b;
    b.insert(linkedList.begin());      // This does not compile

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler message is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'qHash(const QLinkedList<MyType>::iterator&)'
```

I know, that the reason why the first three lines compile is that for the `QVector`, the iterator is defined as `typedef T* iterator;` but for the `QLinkedList` it is a custom type.

I found out, that the `QSet` template class is implemented in terms of a hash table.
Apparently it is possible to evaluate the hash function for a pointer, but not for a custom type.

Please, could you tell me, how to overload the `qHash` function for my program to compile? I have read some basic information on the workings of a hash table, but I lack the confidence in the subject.

I tried to understand the inner workings of the `QLinkedList<T>::iterator`. It seems that it is very similar to the `QVector<T>::iterator`. It just holds a pointer to a node in the linked list instead of a pointer to the item itself.

```
class iterator
{
public:
   ...
   Node *i;
   ...
};
```

So I tried to define the function in this manner:

```
uint qHash(QLinkedList<MyType>::iterator it)
{
    return qHash(it.i);
}
```

The program compiled, but I have no confidence in my solution. How should I correctly overload the `qHash` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did perfectly well already.  The basic rules of hash functions are:

1. If `x = y` then `hash(x) = hash(y)`.
2. If `x != y` then `hash(x) != hash(y)` (as often as possible).  This isn't a strict rule, but the better it's followed, the better the performance of the hash table.  Ideally, the outputs will appear random.

Your way works because if two iterators, `ia` and `ib` are equal (referring to the same node), their internal pointers, `ia.i` and `ib.i` will be equal.  That takes care of rule 1.  Then you use a built-in hash function on those pointers; Qt takes care of rule 2 for you.

Cheers!